# Eclipse RCP/JavaFX 2 - Generating product

Tags: javafx-2, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to generate a RCP application embedding JavaFX 2.0 application using e(fx)clipse with eclipse sdk 4.2.2.  All is working good except the product generation, is there a way around ?
I tried using the nightly build with the 4.3 eclipse SDK but it says that the Bundle "org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench3" is missing.  Also the default generated plug-in application with JavaFX is not as complete as with the eclipse 4.2.2 SDK. So I really would like to know if it is possible to generate a product using the 4.2.2 release of e(fx)clipse.

Comment: How are you generating the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why don't you file a bug if things are not working in the nightly builds?

Anyways I think the problem was that the wiki was not up-to-date. You need to create a custom target platform to get the fx.ui.workbench3-bundle. I've updated the wiki at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial2.

Do yourself a favor and use the nightly builds. All namespaces have shifted and you won't get any support for the pre eclipse versions!